# Syntax error in insert into statement in C# links to MS Access By ADO.NET

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, ms-access, ado.net

Every one 
i write code that insert some data into Microsoft Access database but i have an error "Syntax error in insert into statement" i don't know why !!!
Any one help me ?
thanks in advance ;
    code:

```
 OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data  Source=D:\me\Library Store\Library Store\Store.accdb");
    try
    {
        conn.Open();

        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Libarary ( ISBN, Name, Gategory, Author, Cost, Date) VALUES ( @ISBN, @Name, @Gategory, @Author, @Cost, @Date) ";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ISBN", ISBNTB.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", NameTB.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gategory", GategoryTB.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Author", AuthorTB.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cost", int.Parse(CostTB.Text));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", dateTimePicker1.Text);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            MessageBox.Show("Data Added!");
            conn.Close();


    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When one or more of your fields use a reserved keyword you need to enclose ALWAYS that field in square brackets. (A very annoying problem). In your query, you use two reserved keywords: DATE and NAME

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Libarary ( ISBN, [Name], Gategory, Author, Cost, [Date]) " + 
                  "VALUES ( @ISBN, @Name, @Gategory, @Author, @Cost, @Date) ";
```

If it is not too late, I suggest you to rename these fields to avoid this kind of problem in future.